# Wordpress Bootsrap Menu - align search box to left in smaller responsive views?

Tags: wordpress, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Site URL: http://scc.maxworks.org/wo-wp0001/

I needed to get the search box into the nav menu at the top of the site, which I did (it's a div inside an unordered list) and it places where i want it to when on a computer screen. now i'm trying to get it to behave as I would like to when on a tablet or phone - which is that I'd like to to align to the left side of the screen when you click the menu icon to open the list. (Actually i'd like the search box to appear next to the menu icon but i think thats beyond my skill to do at this time. So i'm trying to align it to the left when in the smaller views.

I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrapwp.css 
find

```
ul#main-menu.nav li form#searchform div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 380px;
}
```

remove padding

```
ul#main-menu.nav li form#searchform div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check [this](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) out. You could use the Responsive utility classes. So put 2 searchboxes in and hide on the not wanted resolution. Might be not the ultra super best way but it works and it is quick.

There might be some fancy js way to accomplish this, can't help you there.